# Linking to TLS libpthread-2.3.4.so library instead of system libpthread library

Tags: linux, pthreads, linker-errors, redhat

I am using functions such as pthread_setaffinity_np from the /usr/include/nptl/pthread.h.

The linker is however complaining that the "pthread_setaffinity_np" is not found, as far as I understand, the linker is looking for the reference in the wrong pthread library (/usr/lib/libpthread.so) which doesn't include support for CPU affinity. I am on RedHat 4.

I believe I have to link to /lib/tls/libpthread-2.3.4.so which includes this function. However linking to libpthread-2.3.4.so caused other linker errors.

What is the proper way of linking to libpthread-2.3.4.so on RedHat 4?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: According to the git history log of glibc, sched_setaffinity_np has been in the tree since 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2):

> as far as I understand, the linker is looking for the reference in the wrong pthread library

Your understanding is *incorrect*.

The `/usr/lib/libpthread.so` is a *linker script*, which links your program with `libpthread.so.0` and `libpthread_nonshared.a`. The `libpthread.so.0` is (should be) a symlink, most likely to `libpthread-2.3.4.so`.

There are likely several versions of `libpthread-2.3.4.so` installed on your system: one in `/lib/i686`, one in `/lib/tls`, perhaps also one in `/lib`. Which one is used at runtime depends on your hardware and your kernel.

What do the following commands print?

```
find /lib -name 'libpthread.so.0' | xargs nm -A | grep pthread_setaffinity_np

ldd /usr/bin/date
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably might not work. NPTL is now in the GNU libc. And it is intimately related to the version of the kernel (and you are probably using some ancient distribution with an old kernel.).

The good solution is to upgrade your system to something providing a recent enough NPTL (and recent enough kernel) to suit your needs. Processor affinity is handled both inside the *pthread* library (often packaged with `libc`) and inside the kernel (because it is related to the scheduler).

Why don't you install e.g. [CentOS 6](http://www.centos.org/) (which is [a derivative of RedHat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centos))?

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading is not an option (I'd love to), due to other reasons.

Comment: Then I guess you are stuck; you need some fairly recent kernel (I cannot tell which); you could try to install a newer distribution inside a chroot.